# SQL(Joining tables Query)

Tags: sql

`Course_info` table:

```
-----------------------------------------------
 COURSE_ID    COURSE_NAME          COURSE_DURATION
----------   -------------------- ---------------
     6      SQL                                3
     7      PF                                12
     8      JAVA                              13
     9      C                                  2
     0      UNIX                               4
```

`FACULTY_INFO` table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
FACULTY_ID   FACULTY_NAME         LOCATION             EXPERIENCE
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
     1   ABC                  DELHI                        10
     2   DEF                  NOIDA                         4
     3   GHI                  GGN                           2
     4   JKL                  HYD                           1
     5   MNO                  GOA                          25
```

`Paper_info` table:

```
FACULTY_ID  COURSE_ID DIFFICULTY_LEVEL     NO_OF_PAPER SUBMITTED
---------- ---------- -------------------- -----------
         1          8 DIFFICULT                      1
         2          9 STANDARD                       5
         3          8 DIFFICULT                      2
         4          7 STANDARD                       5
         5          7 STANDARD                       8
```

Now the query is to retrieve the `course_id` for which no papers were submitted.

This query:

```
select c.course_id
from course_info c, paper_info p
where c.course_id <> p.course_id;
```

gives:

```
COURSE_ID
-------------
6
8
7
9
0 (But 6,7 are not present in course_id of paper_info)
```

Second query:

```
select c.course_id 
from course_info c, paper_info p
where c.course_id not in (select course_id from paper_info);
```

Output:

```
0
6  (Working fine)
```

Whats the difference between the two queries?

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: there is no difference, both are wrong, ( maybe you ask a better question?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wonder why you said that? Is there any advantage when use `JOIN` over `WHERE`?

Comment: @ManhLe Readability, less prone to accidental `CROSS JOIN`s, and not to mention that the implicit `JOIN` syntax was deprecated [*over 25 years ago*](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).  Additionally, the implicit `OUTER JOIN` syntax is [flat out not supported in some DBMS](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (e.g. `SQL Server 2012` or later).

Comment: @ManhLe . . . I rarely bother to answer a question where the query uses archaic join syntax.  I find it much harder to make sense of.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that the second query will exclude the course_id in paper_info. The first query will make a comparison between the two table and the include those that meets your condition.

For example:
Course_info with course_id 8 is equal (has a relation) to paper_info with course_id equal 8. Because of that, that relation will not be included in your results due to your where clause.

However course_id 8 in course_info is not equal to course_id 9 in paper_info. Because of that, that relation will be included. Which is why you see 9 in that first query.

What you should have done was a left join on c.course_id = p.course_id where p.course_id is null

Answer (score 0):

<> in sql means "Not Equal To".

Basically in compares two expressions, returns TRUE if left operand "Not Equal To" right operand. Otherwise FALSE. Remember: In any valid expression. Both expressions must have implicitly convertible data types.

In above example, each COURSE_ID in Course_Info table will be compared with every COURSE_ID in Paper_Info table. Because right hand expression is not a single integer value. It is set of all COURSE_ID's of Paper_Info table, compared one at each time. So I think output will be as below

6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
0
0
0
0
0

Correct me, If I am wrong. Thanks!